# How to open a popup with an argument

Tags: python, kivy, popup, kivy-language

I am trying to open a popup-message with a specific argument (errortype) to define in the popup-kv which text schould be shown.

I've tried it with a seperat class (ErrorPopUp) but i am not able to call the popup-method with the argument.

"'ErrorPopup' object has no attribute 'errortype'"

This should be a reproducible example.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MainWindow(Screen):

    float_weight = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):
        try:
            float_weight = float(self.float_weight.text.replace(',', '.'))
        except:
            ErrorPopup().ErrorMessage('errorweight')

class ErrorPopup(Popup):
    kv = Builder.load_file("error.kv")
    def ErrorMessage(self, errortype):
        Popup.open(self)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
    MyMainApp().run()
```

my.kv:

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    float_weight: float_weight

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "Gewicht:"

            TextInput:
                id: float_weight
                multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Test3"
            on_press:root.btn()
```

error.kv:

```
<ErrorPopup>:
    title: 'Fehlerhafte Eingabe'
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (400, 400)
    Label:
        text: root.errortype
```

Comment: You might want to specify what framework you're using here. Add the necessary imports to the code, and tag the question with that framework, you'll be more likely to attract the attention of people who know that framework.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: Also thanks for your advice. I posted a minimal reproducible example with the kv's also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `error.kv`, you ran `text: root.errortype`. What kivy understands is that there is a variable in the `ErrorPopup` class, but returns an error because it simply does not exist. The variable is within the function `ErrorMessage()` which is inaccessible unless you return it, which is not what you want. My suggestion for your `.py` and `error.kv` files are:

.py

```
class ErrorPopup(Popup):
    kv = Builder.load_file("error.kv")
    def ErrorMessage(self, errortype):
        self.ids.LABEL.text = errortype
        Popup.open(self)
```

error.kv

```
<ErrorPopup>:
    title: 'Fehlerhafte Eingabe'
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (400, 400)
    Label:
        id: LABEL
        text: ''
```

It worked perfectly fine with me, should work with you too!

Comment: It also worked perfectly for me, thanks a lot!!

Comment: No problem! If you don't mind, could you mark it as correct? It would really help build my reputation.